# Using user input numbers to find a word in a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, line

Currently trying to work out how I use user inputs. In my case it is 1/2/3 to find a specific line and word in a text box and copy that information and output the word into a new text box. The text box the user inputs into has already been split so the first number chooses the text file to choose a word from the second number chooses a line and the third number chooses a word. After the first number is read the chosen text file is going to be output into a rich text box before the keyword is discovered and output.

So far I don't have much code towards this but the only part I really don't understand is how to find the specific line and word. Currently the text box with the three user inputs is being broken up into each individual section and being stored in invisible labels for each section as you can see in my code.

Here's my code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int NumLines;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSubmit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var charArray = txtPoemInput.Text.Split('/');   // Dividing the users input into 3 usable sections using invisible labels

        lblPoem.Text = charArray[0];    
        lblLine.Text = charArray[1];
        lblWord.Text = charArray[2];



        // Testing for which poem is going to be used
        if (lblPoem.Text == "1")
        {
            //Read in text file
        }
        else if (lblPoem.Text == "2")
        {
            //Read in text file
        }
        else if (lblPoem.Text == "3")
        {
            //Read in text file
        }

        NumLines = txtPoem.Lines.Count();

        // the user input line and word finds and selects the speciic word required 
        // Displays word in the Keyword box
```

Comment: Can you also share some input file data and the expected output? Based on `1` how do you decide which file to read? Do you need to read locate file from some specific location?

Comment: Are the File listed somewhere (a `List<string>` or similar)? Does `lblLine.Text` references the Line number in which a Word should be found? Is `lblWord.Text` the Word index in the sequence of words in a Line?

Comment: `var charArray = txtPoemInput.Text.Split('/');`  Don't assume you will have three parts in your string.  Always check.

Comment: The labels or lbl's are used to define each of the sections i have to use. The poem one selects one of three poems to use. The line value needs to find that line in the pome ( which once found will be output to the screen into a rich text box) and the word should hopefully find the word in that line. E.G. 1/2/3 would be poem one line 2 word three. I asked my c' teacher he suggested I use invisible list boxes to count the lines and then use a second one to count the words by splitting them with space instead of the slash like i did earlier. Hope this helps clarify.